# something wont allow me to reach websites

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I'm connected to WiFi but can't reach web pages, Firefox returns error: Having trouble finding that site. Can't connect to server at github.com (and all other sites I've tried to open).

I tried opening /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf and this is what it has (ignoring all #)

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns trust-ad
search .
```

I've recently installed Linux and everything was working fine on day 1 but it suddenly just stopped working.

Comment: Which Linux did you install? Old one or new one? Does it have a name and a version number?

Comment: first step should be a ping test, `ping 8.8.8.8`, `ping www.google.com`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try: (if your `systemd` version is older than 239)

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

On newer versions of `systemd` (239 and later), use this instead:

```
sudo resolvectl flush-caches
```

Or if it did not work you can search dns on your settings and remove if there is any other dns

Comment: i got this when i run the command sudo: systemd-resolve command not found

Comment: The command is named `resolvectl` in newer versions..